# How to calculate this force

Tags: calculus

How can I calculate the force exerted on the sides of a trough when the trough is filled with water, in general? Meaning for a given shape and depth of water, how can i calculate the force exerted on a given side of the shape?

Comment: Pressure is a scalar, so force exerted on flat surface of area $\Delta S$ when pressure is $p$ equals $p \Delta S$, no matter how surface is oriented. Could you give more specific example for better understanding what problem you do have?

Comment: Sure, given an isosceles triangular trough (meaning the ends are this shape) with width 4 feet and height 5 feet, find the force exerted on one end of the trough.